# Automatically remove generated latex (junk) files after compilation?

Tags: shell, latex

I was wondering whether there is simple command to delete all unnecessary files generated during the latex compilation process, e.g. .aux, .log, etc.

It would be great to chain it to the regular Latex build commands, so that after I hit "Compile", the junk files are deleted.

As an editing tool, I'm using TeXstudio.

Comment: The `.aux` *is* necessary. And, depending on your project, some others may also be necessary. See [Egad! What are all those files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53240/5764); [File extensions of LaTeX-related files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7770/5764); [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11123/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a shell script that does exactly what you want. It will work on Mac and Linux; with some adjustments Windows should be possible too. Download the file "cleanlatexjunk.sh" from my repository and follow the instructions:

https://github.com/cgraumann/LatexUtils

1. Open *Preferences/Build* in TexStudio
2. Select *Advanced options* at the bottom
3. Add a new user command with the name `cleanjunk`
4. As the command, enter:

   `"/PATH/TO/SCRIPT/cleanlatexjunk.sh" -fp ?me ?a)`

   and change */PATH/TO/SCRIPT/* accordingly
5. In the meta-command for *Build & View* add 

   `| txs:///compile | txs:///compile | txs:///cleanjunk`
    at the end

Now every build & view execution should result in a clean workspace :-)

**Edit**: As mentioned by Werner in the comment, the "junk" files are of course needed during the build process. Therefore the suggested command in step 5 includes two additional compile runs. This assures that all TOCs and links are rendered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to build latex into pdf or save the command into file `build.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex
rm -r -f *.aux *.log *.lof *.gz *.toc *.bak~
```

Run command `chmod +x build.sh` to make file executable.
Now run `./build.sh` in terminal to produce output.

Answer (score 1):

The `latexmk` command line utility has the `-c` option for cleaning out the auxiliary files.

It's been a while since I used `TexStudio` but I think it relies on `latexmk` and in the settings/preferences you can configure the call to `latexmk` to include the `-c` option.

Comment: You have to configure texstudio to use latexmk. By default it compiles with ordinary pdflatex.

Answer (score 1):

These files are neither unnecessary nor junk. If you remove them, you'll have to spend more time when you next compile your code because you have to compile the document multiple times, re-run bibliography tools etc. Best don't delete them, this will save a lot of time.

If you really, really can't live with these files, have a look at https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any . If you compile your file with

ltx2any filename

the tool will automatically copy all the necessary files in a temporary directory, make all the necessary compilation steps and copy back the results. This way you combine best of both worlds, you have a clean directory and latex has all the files it needs to compile your document.

To use this in texstudio, you can add a user command:

[image]

(as text for copy&pasting: `<your path to the program>/ltx2any -lf raw -synctex % | txs:///view-pdf`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [clean](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clean/) from `crontab` (it runs in every 3 hours). It deletes all `*.aux` and `*.log` files which older than 1 day - using `-t` option (because `aux` is necessary as Werner wrote above).

I think you can use this command from your editor too as wrote `Captain Ahab` above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Kile** editor (similar to TexStudio). It has the option to remove auxiliary files when Kile is exited. Just go to *Settings* -> *Configure Kile* and the automatic cleaning option appears immediately.

[image]

To install Kile on Linux just run the command

```
sudo apt install kile
```

In addition to solving the pollution problem, Kile solved another TexStudio problem with text autocompletion. TexStudio only autocompletes commands, it does not complete common or repeated text, Kile does, which is an even more serious problem.